# Remove nTh record from array using loop

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm writing a program that reads a .csv file, and then loops through it removing every 10th record it encounters before outputting it.

I've been stuck on what I believe is a syntax issue for a while now and just can't seem to nail it. Anyone mind having a look?

```
lines = []
i = 0

elements = []
element2 = []
output = []

file = File.open("./properties.csv", "r")

while (line = file.gets)
    i += 1
  # use split to break array up using commas
    arr = line.split(',')
    elements.push({ id: arr[0], streetAddress: arr[1], town: arr[2], valuationDate: arr[3], value: arr[4] })
end

file.close

# filter out blanks and nill rows
x = elements.select { |elements| elements[:id].to_i >= 0.1}

# Loop to remove every 10th record
e = 0 
d = 1

loop do x.length
    if e == (10 * d)
        d ++ 
        e ++
    else
        x = elements.select[e]
        e ++
end

puts x

puts "#{x.length} house in list, #{d} records skipped."

CSV FILE
ID,Street address,Town,Valuation date,Value
1,1 Northburn RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,280000
2,1 Mount Ida PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,280000
3,1 Mount Linton AVE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,780000
4,1 Kamahi ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,155000
5,1 Kapuka LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,149000
6,1 Mohua MEWS,WANAKA,1/1/2015,560000
7,1 Kakapo CT,WANAKA,1/1/2015,430000
8,1 Mt Gold PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1260000
9,1 Penrith Park DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1250000
10,1 ATHERTON PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,650000
11,1 WAIMANA PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,780000
12,1 ROTO PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1470000
13,1 Toms WAY,WANAKA,1/1/2015,2230000
14,1 MULBERRY LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,415000
15,1 Range View PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,300000
16,1 Clearview ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1230000
17,1 Clutha PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,700000
18,1 Centre CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,295000
19,1 Valley CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,790000
20,1 Edgewood PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,365000
21,1 HUNTER CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,335000
22,1 KOWHAI DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,480000
23,1 RIMU LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,465000
24,1 CHERRY CT,WANAKA,1/1/2015,495000
25,1 COLLINS ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,520000
26,1 AUBREY RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,985000
27,1 EELY POINT RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,560000
28,1 LINDSAY PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,385000
29,1 WINDERS ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,760000
30,1 Manuka CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,510000
31,1 WILEY RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,420000
32,1 Baker GR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,820000
33,1 Briar Bank  DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1260000
34,1 LAKESIDE RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,440000
35,1 PLANTATION RD,WANAKA,1/1/2015,345000
36,1 Allenby PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,640000
37,1 ROB ROY LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,380000
38,1 Ansted PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,590000
39,1 Fastness CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,640000
40,1 APOLLO PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,385000
41,1 AEOLUS PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,370000
42,1 Peak View RDGE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1750000
43,1 Moncrieff  PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,530000
44,1 Islington PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,190000
45,1 Hidden Hills DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1280000
46,1 Weatherall CL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,425000
47,1 Terranova PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,900000
48,1 Cliff Wilson ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1200000
49,1 TOTARA TCE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,460000
50,1 Koru WAY,WANAKA,1/1/2015,570000
51,1 Bovett PL,Wanaka,1/1/2015,495000
52,1 Pearce PL,Wanaka,1/1/2015,675000
53,1 Ironside DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,570000
54,1 Bob Lee PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,610000
55,1 Hogan LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,395000
56,1 ARDMORE ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1190000
57,1 Bullock Creek LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,11125000
58,1 DUNMORE ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1300000
59,1 Primary LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,430000
60,1 SYCAMORE PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,720000
61,1 FAULKS TCE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,780000
62,1 Alpha CL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,500000
63,1 Coromandel ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,530000
64,1 Niger ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,475000
65,1 Maggies Way,WANAKA,1/1/2015,375000
66,1 Hollyhock LANE,QUEENSTOWN,1/1/2015,1080000
67,1 ELDERBERRY CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1340000
68,1 Foxglove HTS,WANAKA,1/1/2015,2520000
69,1 MEADOWSTONE DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,650000
70,1 OAKWOOD PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,580000
71,1 MEADOWBROOK PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,645000
72,1 Jessies CRES,WANAKA,1/1/2015,320000
73,1 Lansdown ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,700000
74,1 Stonebrook DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,640000
75,1 Hyland ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,500000
76,1 TAPLEY PADDOCK,WANAKA,1/1/2015,720000
77,1 Homestead CL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1750000
78,1 NORMAN TCE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,620000
79,1 Sunrise Bay DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,3000000
80,1 LARCH PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,570000
81,1 MILL END,WANAKA,1/1/2015,600000
82,1 Bills WAY,WANAKA,1/1/2015,750000
83,1 Heuchan LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,610000
84,1 SARGOOD DR,WANAKA,1/1/2015,455000
85,1 Frederick ST,WANAKA,1/1/2015,455000
86,1 Connell TCE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,600000
87,1 Soho ST,QUEENSTOWN,1/1/2015,320000
88,1 Hikuwai DR,ALBERT TOWN,1/1/2015,280000
89,1 Harrier LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,1000000
90,1 Ewing PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,780000
91,1 Sherwin AVE,ALBERT TOWN,1/1/2015,440000
92,1 Hardie PL,WANAKA,1/1/2015,830000
93,1 Finch ST,ALBERT TOWN,1/1/2015,540000
94,1 Poppy LANE,ALBERT TOWN,1/1/2015,395000
95,1 Warbler LANE,ALBERT TOWN,1/1/2015,410000
96,1 Balneaves LANE,WANAKA,1/1/2015,250000
97,1 Mill Green,Arrowtown,1/1/2015,800000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'csv'

elements = {}

CSV.foreach("properties.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
    elements[row.fields[0]] = Hash[row.headers[1..-1].zip(row.fields[1..-1])]
end

d = 0
e = 0
elements.delete_if do |key, value|
  e += 1

  if e == 10
    e = 0
    d += 1
  end

  e == 0
end

puts "#{elements.length} house in list, #{d} records skipped."
```

At the end of this, elements will have every 10th row removed, and `d` contains the number of rows removed.